# Conditional Where clauses in JasperReports

Tags: sql, jasper-reports, where-clause

Let's say I want a JasperReport that lets the user filter on a date if they so wish.  The SQL is as follows:

```
select * from foo where bar = $P{bar} and some_date > $P{some.date}
```

Now, I don't want to filter by some date if they didn't pass the date in.  I found the following kludge that people use:

```
select * from foo where bar = $P{bar} $P!{some.date.fragment}
```

And the `some.date.fragment` parameter is defined with the following default:

```
($P{some.date} == null || $P{some.date}.equals("")) ? "" : "AND some_date >'" + new java.sql.Date($P{some.date}.getTime()).toString() + "'"
```

This is not working as the `toString` doesn't output the date in a format that my SQL server understands.  I would like to have the conditional still use a prepared statement with the jdbc driver and toss the parameter in, I just want the prepared statement to be dependent on if the parameter is null or not.  Can this be done?

Comment: In my case the second parameter was a string and the part of the where clause I used $P{stringValue}.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before you have used the `$P!{}` expression the JDBC-Driver does all formatting for you.

But if you use the `$P!{}` expression you have to format yourself.

Something like this should work:

```
(
$P{some.date} == null 
? 
"" 
: 
"AND some_date >'" + (new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS")).format($P{some.date}) + "'"
)
```

Depending on your  data type you have to customize `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS`.

If you don't want to use the `$P!{}` expression you can avoid it with the solution below.

*I personally don't like this way. It also may cause a bad execution plan.*

If don't want to use `$P!{}` because you worry about sql injection. It's needless as long your parameter `$P{some.date}` contains a safe data type like `java.lang.Date`.

---

Create a parameter. Let's call it `${is_null_pram}` and add a default expression with param class `Integer`:

```
($P{some.date} == null ? 1 : 0)
```

Now you can query:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM foo 
WHERE
    bar = $P{bar}
    AND
        (
            some_date > $P{some.date}
            OR 1 = $P{is_null_pram}
        )
```

Comment: Well neither of those solutions are what I would want as an ideal solution.  I want the null parameter to change the sql being executed, but I also want the jdbc driver to parameterize input.  I hate figuring out the date formatting, etc.  The second options seems better though, and I did some testing with show plan/explain plan and the databases handle the OR appropriately by ignoreing the predicate if there is a 1=1 true condition.

Comment: Just an FYI to anyone that sees this.  Have `is_null_param` be an integer that you compare to another 1.  The string comparison doesn't get optimized as well by some of the databases.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the function:

`$X{EQUAL, <column_name>, <parameter_name>}`

It optimizes the query as you can see in [this](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/query/index.html) help page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this conditional statement

```
    select * 
    from foo 
    where bar = $P{bar} and some_date > $P{some.date} or $P{some.date}  is null
```